# Updating the content of dependency jar in Gradle

Tags: gwt, gradle

I'm trying to compile the javadoc for my Gradle application but it seems to crash on one of the dependencies. Specifically, the `gwt-user-2.4.0.jar` file. I've already figured out that the problem lies in the fact that the file contains both the `.class` and `.java` files and it's trying to compile the java files.

For now I'm just trying to get it fixed quickly until I know how to deal with the underlying problem by just removing the `.java` files from the jar. I'm trying to accomplish this by adding the following code to my `build.gradle`:

```
javadoc{
    newjar = jar {
        from zipTree("${project.configurations.compile.find{it.name == 'gwt-user-2.4.0.jar'}}") {
            exclude "**/*.java"
        }
        destinationDir = file("${project.buildDir}/temp")
        baseName = "gwt-user-2.4.0.new"

    }
    classpath -= files(project.configurations.compile.find{it.name == "gwt-user-2.4.0.jar"})
    classpath += newjar
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I can't find anything in the documentation on how to copy content from one jar to another or something alike. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

**TL;DR**: How do I alter content from a jar file in Gradle?

Comment: I do not think standard Gradle has task to disassemble archives, but you can always create your own task to achieve that, such as http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html. As to the crash problem, what is your original javadoc closure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating javadoc with gwt-user.jar through Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562064/creating-javadoc-with-gwt-user-jar-through-gradle)