# Creating javadoc with gwt-user.jar through Gradle

Tags: gwt, javadoc, gradle

I'm trying to compile the javadocs for my application, and for some reason it throws errors while compiling like this:

```
/Users/Sander/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/jar/949dcb5d14cb0e2c8dec98efc0760be68753c124/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar(com/google/gwt/dom/client/CanvasElement.java):18: error: cannot access Context
import com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context;
```

All the errors thrown are found in `gwt-user-2.4.0.jar`. Basically, what (I think) it's trying to do is compile the `.java` source files the jar file contains, which it shouldn't do. Is there a way to make the javadoc command ignore java source files?

I've tried removing the source files from the jar manually, this way the build succeeds. However, since the jar is a gradle dependency, manually altering the file is not an option.

Comment: Since IntelliJ was able to generate the docs for some reason, I started comparing the two methods. It seems that the only way of escaping the errors is to add a `-sourcepath` flag to the `javadoc` command, this makes the build succeed. However, there seems to be no equivalent to this flag in the Gradle DSL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work. As it turned out, the javadoc command needed a `sourcepath` flag set, because otherwise it would start looking for the source files in the classpath, which contained some source files from the GWT jar file. Since the `MinimalJavaDocOptions` GWT class doesn't support this, I had to set it manually by adding the following line:

`options.addStringOption("sourcepath", <path_to_source>)`

This fixed the problem. Obviously it is not ideal, a topic in the Gradle Support Forums has already been created, see http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/allow_javadoc_sourcepath_to_be_set_directly